# How can I fix JSON Duplicate Key?

Tags: json

I've never programed anything before and have no experience :) I'm using a program which I get from github and now I have to make a json settings file for it.

basicly, I'll pick fix(ASMAP or BARPE) and runway(35L or 36) and the program should give me the right "dep"/"nap" and "cfl" for these settings. But there are more than one possible cfl and runway for a fix which is causing me duplicate key warning. can anybody help me about how to overcome this problem? I'll share just a little part of the code for you to see the structure:

```
"ASMAP": {"cfl": 5000, "rwys": {"35L": {"dep": "ASMAP3D", "nap": "ASMAP3R"},"35R":{"dep":"ASMAP3D", "nap": "ASMAP3R"}}},
"ASMAP": {"cfl": 8000, "rwys": {"36": {"dep": "ASMAP3E", "nap": "ASMAP3S"}}},
"BARPE": {"cfl": 5000, "rwys": {"35L": {"dep": "BARPE3D"}, "35R": {"dep": "BARPE3D"}}},
"BARPE": {"cfl": 8000, "rwys": {"36": {"dep": "BARPE3E"}}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong data structure.

A hashmap's (what you are using) keys must be unique. You have multiple keys that are not unique:

```
{
 "ASMAP": { ... }
 "ASMAP": { ... } <- this is the same key as above
}
```

To help you thinking about it, the reason why they must be unique is because when you attempt to access a value by key, if the keys are not unique, then the hashmap doesn't know which value you are trying to access.

So, you could use a different data structure like this:

```
{
 "ASMAP": [
   {"cfl": 5000, "rwys": {"35L": {"dep": "ASMAP3D", "nap": "ASMAP3R"},"35R":{"dep":"ASMAP3D", "nap": "ASMAP3R"}}},
   {"cfl": 8000, "rwys": {"36": {"dep": "ASMAP3E", "nap": "ASMAP3S"}}}
 ],
 "BARPE": [ ... ]
}
```

Now, `ASMAP` and `BARPE` are unique keys, and their values contain a list.

Comment: Thank you it fixed the problem.